# IPV6 validation issue

Tags: java, javascript, validation, ipv6

I'm working on IPV6 validation both server (java) and client (javascript) side and i have Incompatibility issue with the following IPs:

1. 02001:0000:1234:0000:0000:C1C0:ABCD:0876
2. 2001:0000:1234:0000:00001:C1C0:ABCD:0876

both of them have an extra zero and looks invalid to me.

My javascript validation (based on http://www.intermapper.com/support/tools/IPV6-Validator.aspx) return invalid but my server side says it's a valid IP.

In the server side, I'm checking 2 options:
1. java.net.InetAddress.getByName("");
2. com.google.common.net.InetAddresses.isInetAddress("");

Can you please advise?

Thanks!

Comment: why invalid? `0x02001` and `0x2001` represent the same value.

Comment: Correct. I just thought it's wrong cause i checked it in several IPv6 online validator.

Comment: Are you interested in what the RFC says? Before you get a definite answer, it's probably a good idea to consult your usecase instead of taking the letter of the law.

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in what the RFC says. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KobiM - In that case, you should read the RFC :-).  Seriously, for things related to internet standards you should be prepared to find the correct RFC and read it carefully ... before asking questions.

Comment: May I ask what generated those addresses?

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 4291](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291) describes the textual representation of IPv6 addresses.

It specifies that each of the fields is "one to four hexadecimal digits" (section 2.2). This is in line with the fact that the IPv6 address is a 128-bit binary value ([RFC 3587](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3587)); thus any extra digits would cause the value to be more than 128 bits and therefore invalid..

Whatever tool you are using that said these addresses are valid, it is broken.